# Why does the prototyping day of the Design Sprint suck for the team?

Tags: prototype

OK, we just ran our first (Google Ventures) Design Sprint according to Jake Knapp's et. al. "Sprint" book. It was a very productive and overall pleasant event.

Putting on my meta UX hat, I handed out questionnaires at the end of every day to gather feedback for the individual activities conducted and the overall approval of the results that the team achieved that day.

We were to re-envision a very old school Windows Desktop B2B application. Everything was honky dory, until we reached the prototyping day. We went into the day with a detailed story board and a clear vision of what had to be build.

The product should look like a native Windows Office application. Hence, we followed the book's recommendation to use PowerPoint. To speed up things, we bought a set of templates from Keynotopia for not having to build windows, buttons and the like ourselves.

However, it wasn't too much fun, after all. These were my team's responses on a 5-point Likert scale (0 = Don't agree at all; 4 = Fully agree]:

- I like the resulting prototype: mean 1.7, median 2
- PowerPoint was the right choice as prototyping tool: mean 0.7, median 1
- Keynotopia templates were a time-saver: mean 1.3, median 1

From my observation, one major problem was the limited ability to split up remaining work once the stitcher started to put things together, and missing features like layers and symbols like one has in Illustrator.

> "Stitcher" is a term from the Sprint book. It refers to the person who gathers individual screens and components from the "Makers", who create these parts. Her task is to iron out inconsistencies and stitch the screens together to form the complete prototype.

The only thing that prevented the Sprint from falling apart was the fact that prototyping happened on Friday and User Tests were scheduled for Monday. So some weekend-heroics yielded a polished prototype which actually outperformed our existing software significantly (in the statistical sense, 5 users filled out a SUS-questionnaire each for the old software and the PowerPoint-prototype).

So in the end the Sprint was a full success. However, I'd rather not expose my team to a set of tools that let them down before.

Has anyone encountered a situation like this before? Is it a tooling problem? Is it a coordination problem?

**Edit:** After fixing the prototype on the weekend the result was rated 3.7 on the [0..4]-scale, and all team-members would wholeheartedly recommend the Design Sprint to a friend with a design problem.

Comment: GV = Google Ventures? Are you following their Sprint book?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, if that was not clear.

Comment: Sounds pretty clear that one day is not enough time to design a prototype, and that you chose poor tools (powerpoint!)  to do so.    (FWIW, and here I move into Highly Opinionated Mode: "agile methodology essentially a failure, rescued only by weekend heroics" is a very, very familiar story.  Agile is (finally) starting to fall out of favor in the development world; it's very disappointing to see it start to infect the design world...)

Comment: @DanielBeck, I don't see any mention to Agile on the question

Comment: @Devin, "sprint" is agile jargon.  GV's Sprint book carefully avoids using the word "agile" -- see above re "finally starting to fall out of favor" -- but it's obviously a light reskin of the same methodology.

Comment: Ah ok. I know sprint is used in Agile, but really don't know about GV. For what I see at first glimpse has some similarities, but also some huge differences. Will need to dive deep into this :)

Comment: I'd like to point out that overall the method actually yielded quite impressive results. Basically, we were one day short. Compared to other planning schemes that I've seen in development just going  20% over budget to reach the target sounds like a dream. And right on target we were: The finished prototype provoked very positive reactions. Also, all the data we collected underlines that our design outperforms the existing product on every level. I most certainly would consider to repeat a Design Sprint to tackle such a re-design in the future.

Comment: @DanielBeck What other tool set would you recommend to prototype a B2B Windows Desktop application (also using Windows as development plattform). We need all the boring stuff: Windows, dialogs, toolbars, list views/grids, tiles, side bars, dashboards, etc. with a native look and feel. Also, the final result has to look real for the most part, no wire frames like Balsamiq.

Comment: Do you know exactly *why* they disliked it? Was it because of using Powerpoint as a prototyping tool? Or perhaps the time constraint? Maybe misunderstanding the concept of prototype and expecting too much out of a prototype? Some qualitative information might supplement the quantitative data.

Comment: @Chris TBH everything about this process -- from the idea that a first-draft prototype needs to "look real", to the idea that disparate components of a design can just be "stitched together" into anything like a coherent product, to your description of those abysmal likert scores the actual process resulted in as "full success" (seems like the real credit belongs to whoever went off script and did the "weekend heroics") -- seems so fundamentally wrong-headed to me that I don't think any advice I'd have to offer would be useful to you.

Comment: (That said I will readily admit I have a gigantic chip on my shoulder with respect to Agile or anything based on it -- like I said, Highly Opinionated Mode.  If you feel it was successful, more power to you.  Your design team members might be the people you should ask about their preferred toolsets.)

Comment: @DanielBeck: "Highly successful" meant the reception of both the prototype and the process as such. With only five test participants we already achieved a significant improvement over the existing software. Also, the whole week was rated a solid 4 by the entire team. Obviously, the prototyping day is something that we need to change up. We'll run an experiment with Axure next week and see if that works better.

Comment: @visualbear: The team was a little skewed towards UX-pros and engineers. So they would have been capable of working with more sophisticated tools. I felt their frustration over not having lockable objects, layers and something akin to Illustrator symbols (having one master-object with many instances, so that changes to one will result in changing all). PowerPoint just has master slides. Since the interactions to pick and select individual parts became tricky real quick, we used master slides mostly as replacement for layers. So design changes to a component had to be made on a lot of copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only a day to prototype it depends of how many tasks you want your testers to perform, and how complex those interactions are. If you think that static screens will do the job, I would probably go for Invision, for its colaboration features and interaction helpers, and still very simple and fast. You would have do create your static screens in whatever software you prefer and import the jpgs or pdfs to Invision.
If you need a rich prototype, with some transitions and conditions, I will go with Axure.
Apart of all that, you really need those assets ready-made to save time.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Invision and Axure. In my experience, Axure gets almost everything done, but requires more time and effort than let's say Balsamiq or PowerPoint. I guess adding a day or two to the design sprint would be required. Would that be a fair assessment?

Comment: Yes, it could be enough, but it always depends of the project. If it's a big project, I would break it in small bits, test, refine, and then move to the next bit, as you advance you will have more and more information, allowing you to make informed decisions on going.
I love the prototyping day, it's where things gets more real. Our team decide what are the top tasks to test and then I try to simulate (as perfect as I can) the patterns behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

At the very beginning of a design I find anything more constrained than a whiteboard or paper and pen to be a big slowdown to creativity and overall speed of unleashing ideas.

Only after a basic flow/layout is determined do I get into digital tools.

Comment: We had a pretty good storyboard with 15 panels/screens (even some content, not just wireframes) before we started "implementing" the real prototype. At least in my opinion, lack of preparation was not the issue.

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm confused then. What were you doing in PowerPoint? Were you transferring the designs into PowerPoint in a group setting (eg 1 person builds while the rest watch?) I've found that group activities work best when everyone can contribute. If this was a room full of people watching one person build I can see how it would be boring for everyone else.

Comment: We broke up the Storyboard into individual components. One Person would create a "Desktop", one the main application window. Another would create some dialog window, the next pop-ups. According to the book, these parts are supposed to be ready in the early afternoon, when one person would start stitching them together. However, we never actually reached that part of the day.